# Import data from dbf file to SQL SErver 2005

Tags: dbf

I received a dbf file from one of our vendors. I need to export that data into one of the tables in SQL Server 2005.

When I try to import data by going to Tasks->Import I dont get an option to select dbf file.

I need your help finding an easy way of accomplishing this task

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an SSIS package to accomplish this. You would create a new ODBC source pointing to your dbase file which will allow you to then tranform and import the data into SQL.

see this for more information on Integration Services: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137712(SQL.90).aspx